# Recursive function that prints the binary representation of the integer

Tags: python, recursion

so i have started the code, and i know that everything after the 'else' is probably wrong:

```
def binary(n):
    if n < 2:
        print (n)
    else:
        x = (bin(int(n)//2)
        print (x)
```

it should do this recursively:

```
>>> binary(0)
0
>>> binary(1)
1
>>> binary(3)
11
>>> binary(9)
1001
```

i do need the function to **print** the binary representation rather than return.

Comment: why don't you use bin if using python:
In [1]: bin(9)  
Out[1]: '0b1001'

Comment: @Ignacio built-in bin function using his binary function and we have a mutual one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work as expected, as you have print in two places, you will end up with multiple lines, e.g.:

```
>>> def binary(n):
...   if n < 2:
...     print n
...   else:
...     binary(n / 2)
...     print n % 2
... 
>>> binary(0)
0
>>> binary(1)
1
>>> binary(3)
1
1
>>> binary(9)
1
0
0
1
>>> binary(10)
1
0
1
0
```

Other answers use strings, so here's one with lists: :)

```
>>> def binary(n):
...   if n < 2:
...     return [n]
...   else:
...     return binary(n / 2) + [n % 2]
... 
>>> binary(0)
[0]
>>> binary(1)
[1]
>>> binary(3)
[1, 1]
>>> binary(9)
[1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> binary(10)
[1, 0, 1, 0]
```

and if you really want a string, it's as simple as this: :)

```
>>> ''.join(map(str, binary(10)))
'1010'
```

Of course, since you've already found out about the function [bin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bin), you should probably have done this in the first place:

```
>>> bin(10)[2:]
'1010'
```

How this reminds me of this:

- http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html

Happy coding! :)

Comment: you're answer is great! for the first solution that you provided, is there any way to make it print horizontally? i tried "print(n%2, end='') but that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
def binary(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return str(binary(n / 2)) + str(n % 2)


print binary(9)
```

It `return`s instead of `print`s, but usually that's better.

Comment: hmm i tried this, but the result i get when i try "binary(3)" is   

>>> binary(3)  
1  
'None1'

Comment: @AngelE: I don't - I get "11"

Comment: i figured it out, i was putting print rather than return. But i need this function to print and not return unfortunately :(

Comment: @AngelE: You can't just say "print binary(3)"?

Answer (score 0):

I would make it return a string instead of printing directly, it would make things much simpler. Like this:

```
def binary(n):
    s = str(n % 2)

    if n >> 1 > 0:
        s += binary(n >> 1)

    return s

print binary(9)
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/9cX4IFc3)